# Error in check_twitter_oauth() : OAuth authentication error

Tags: r, authentication, twitter, oauth

I am trying to extract tweets from twitter using R. While establishing a connection to twitter API , I am getting below authentication error :

```
> setup_twitter_oauth(api_key, api_secret, token, token_secret)
[1] "Using direct authentication"
Error in check_twitter_oauth() : OAuth authentication error:
This most likely means that you have incorrectly called setup_twitter_oauth()'
```

This is the code I am using :

```
api_key <- "api_key here"
api_secret <- "api_secret here"
access_token <- "access_token here"
access_token_secret <- "access_token_secret here "
setup_twitter_oauth(api_key,api_secret,access_token,access_token_secret)
```

My R session is :

```
Session info 
 ------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
 system   x86_64, linux-gnu           
 ui       RStudio (0.99.489)          
 language (EN)                        
 collate  en_US.UTF-8                 
 tz       <NA>                        
 date     2016-01-19
```

I have tried regenerating access and token keys , creating new app , updating the call back URL but still my problem is not resolved.

As suggested I have updated httr and twitteR packages to latest version but still I am getting the errors.

Please find the below errors I am getting :

```
> setup_twitter_oauth(api_key, api_secret, token, token_secret)
[1] "Using direct authentication"
Use a local file to cache OAuth access credentials between R sessions?
1: Yes
2: No

Selection: 1
Adding .httr-oauth to .gitignore
Error in file(con, "w") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "w") : cannot open file '.gitignore': Permission denied 

> setup_twitter_oauth(api_key, api_secret, token, token_secret)
[1] "Using direct authentication"
Use a local file to cache OAuth access credentials between R sessions?
1: Yes
2: No

Selection: 2
Error in check_twitter_oauth() : OAuth authentication error:
This most likely means that you have incorrectly called setup_twitter_oauth()'
```

Please provide your suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: Twitter has been down during the last couple of hours. Could that be the source of your problem?

Comment: What version of `twitteR` and `httr` are you using?

Comment: @brittenb Please find the below package versions I am using                 > packageVersion("twitteR")
[1] ‘1.1.9’
> packageVersion("httr")
[1] ‘0.6.0’
>

Comment: Your `httr` package could use some updating. `twitteR` relies on that package and there was some issues between the two for a while. Since then, the package manager for `twitteR` made updates to rely on the most recent version of `httr`. Given your package version, I suspect that's the issue. Also, you'll want to make sure you install the `base64enc` package. You can check out the conversation around this topic [here](https://github.com/geoffjentry/twitteR/issues/90).

Comment: @brittenb I updated  `httr` and `twitter` packages but still I am getting the same error.

Comment: And you have the `base64enc` package installed?